# Encode digital information to DNA

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequence

DNA Is a Structure That Encodes Biological Information.
Recently DNA is used to encode digital information. (i.e. translate digital Information like photo, text, etc to DNA sequence.
What algorithm is used exactly for translating binary to DNA sequence?

As Wikipedia claims:

> 5.5 petabits can be stored in each cubic millimeter of DNA

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_digital_data_storage

so it is efficient way for storing huge amount of information in DNA.
Is there any good Reference or tutorial book that trains how to encode information to DNA efficiently and decode them again to original information?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest to study molecular biology. You'd need to understand biochemistry behind DNA replication and transcription, what are nucleotides, how cell works, how nucleus works, and many, many other areas; it's really not a matter of some tutorial, or a book (I'm trained in bioinformatics, biophysics, and molecular biology). To the rest of your question - since DNA uses four different nucleotides, you can encode two bits into one nucleotide, e.g. 00b = A, 01b = T, 10b = C, 11b = G.

Comment: So if I want work in this field I should study all these areas(bioinformatics, biophysics, molecular biology and biochemistry )?

Comment: That depends on what specifically you want to do. If your main area is computer science that utilizes biomolecules, I'd focus on computer science and molecular biology (for me, biophysics is necessary, since I design dynamic molecular simulations). C.Sc. only with rudimentary biological knowledge isn't enough, because without solid connection to biological reality usually leads pure computer scientists to astray. I saw many models that are great mathematically, but useless in biological reality.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of concept came from [here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v494/n7435/full/nature11875.html):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it practical: Not yet. It will substitute the common hard-drives/flash disks? No, with the current technology.

If want to learn more about DNA technology, from the biochemistry perspective I advise you to give a look into [DNA replication](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NKH2B9sklEE) and study a bit of DNA chemistry. 
If you a interested in the [current DNA technology sequencing.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8n2LvJ-m0n0)
And will find better a probably answer/discussion at [biostar](https://www.biostars.org/)!

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Do you think if I want to study in this field should I pass long-term of bachelor in biology (all 3 years)? Or just pass some courses of molecular biology and biochemistry is enough?

Comment: Well, i would recommend an interdisciplinary course with at least 50% biology. Biotechnology or biomedical engineering. Pure biology wont give the feel, I am afraid. Unless a very modern one.